Pentaho post image file as field
Would think this request should be pretty standard, but I haven't seen a clear or working answer yet. I simply want to post an image along with settings to a form that accepts. Curl command works; however, I don't see any doc on how to post e.g. HTTP Post vs REST Client? What are the fields to set? etc
Thanks ~
